# Recursive Method giving me errors

Tags: java, recursion

Hello I am trying to make a recursive method for a class assignment. The assignment reads:

In the Person class implement a method that calculates an indicator m based on the following formula using recursion:

m(age) = 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/5 … + 1/age

I have already made the person class previously. So everything works fine on that. However implementing this recursive method into it is giving me errors. My if statement in the recursive method says incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Boolean. I don't see where it thinks I am doing a Boolean variable conversion though. Additionally, where I have my recursion within my method it says, unexpected type.

```
/**
 *
 * @author Randy
 */
public class Person2 {//begin class
    //declare variables
    String name;
    int year_of_birth;
    boolean isStudying;
    boolean isEmployed;
    int age;
    int result;

public Person2(boolean isEmployed, boolean isStudying){//begin constructor
    this.isEmployed = isEmployed;
    this.isStudying = isStudying;
}//end constructor

public Person2(){//begin constructor
    this.isEmployed = false;
    this.isStudying = false;
}//end constructor

public int getYear(){//get year method
        return year_of_birth;
}//end method

public String getName(){//get name method
        return name;
}//end method

public boolean getEmployed(){//get employed method
        return isEmployed;
}//end method

public boolean getStudying(){//get employed method
        return isStudying;
    }//end method

public int getAge(int year_of_birth){//get year method
        age = 2014 - year_of_birth;
    return age;
}//end method

public int rec(int n){//recursive method
    n++;
    result = 1 / n;
    if (age = n){
        return age;
    }
    return rec(int n);
}

public String getStatus(int age) { //begin method
    this.age = age;
    if (age <= 30 && isStudying == true && isEmployed == false) {
        System.out.println(name + " is a student");
    } else if (age >= 30 && age <= 65 && isStudying == false && isEmployed == true) {
        System.out.println(name + " is an employee");
    } else if (age >= 65 && isStudying == false && isEmployed == false) {
        System.out.println(name + " is retired");
    } else {
        System.out.println(name + " is something else");
    }
    return ("");
} //end method

public void setName(String name){//set name method
        this.name = name;
}//end method

public void setYear (int year){//set year method
        this.year_of_birth = year;
}//end method

public void setEmployed(boolean employed){//set employed method
        this.isEmployed = employed;
}//end method

public void setAge (int age){//set year method
        this.age = age;
}//end method
}//end class
```

Comment: `if (age = n)` wasn't what you meant to type, was it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*First Error*

```
if (age = n)
```

This should be

```
if (age == n)
```

Since you're comparing, and not assigning.

The reason it's saying "boolean conversion" is that the assignment statement `age = n` returns the new value of `age`, which is an `int`. And it's expected that an `if` statement takes a boolean value.

*Second Error*

For "unexpected type", change the last line from `return rec(int n);` to `return rec(n);`. There shouldn't be an `int` there, which is why you get "unexpected type".

*Third Error*

After you fix these bugs, check your logic. Your current recursive function doesn't do what it's supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

Your program has some errors:

- Your statement

`if (age = n)`

should be

```
if (age == n).
```

- Variable  `result is type int`  so for all values of n, result is 0 or 1.
  *`return rec(int n)`

should be

`return rec(n)`.

- Check your logic for recursion